# Gitlab - pipeline always fail when try to deploy in docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

When I deploy my pipeline always faile with this error, but when i retry the job the deploy pass.

This could be a error in the instances when try to download the image?

```sh
Command exited with status 1.
(no stdout)
=== stderr ===
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
-  ---  -  ---  -  ---  -  ---  -  ---  -  ---  ----  -  ---  -  -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the shared runners' fault try checking this [issue on gitlab](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-intermittent-error/26698/2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the questions.
Please provide the docker permission to your gitlab-runner user

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```